# Change the size of UIimage before set on the imageview

Tags: iphone

There is a imageview of size 504x320 and image size 1080x1920 which is large than imageview, I want to change the size of this image same as imageview without changing the quality and content of image. I am using this method and this working good but this method little bit crop  to actual image

```
    - (UIImage*)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = image;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO)
    {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        scaledWidth = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else
            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
            }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    if(newImage == nil) 
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Quality and contents (due to scaling the image) will be changed regardless... how have you tried to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading the image with the help of resizing it by the following method.

```
- (UIImage *)editImage:(UIImage *)_image screenWidth:(CGFloat)_width {


CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(_width, _width);

if (isRetinaDisplay])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 2.0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, _width, _width));

CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((_width-_image.size.width)/2, (_width-_image.size.height)/2, _image.size.width, _image.size.height);

[_image drawInRect:imageRect];

UIImage * resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return resizedImage;
}
```

PS: No need to pass the height of the image. Based on aspect fit, it'll get calculated inside.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Look at content view modes of UIImageView, I think Aspect Fit is what you'd want

EDIT after downvotes

```
    [_img_view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit]
```

or

```
    [_img_view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]
```

The former might have spaces at the top/bottom or left/right to preserve the aspect ratio
The latter will have no spaces but might occlude top/bottom or left/right of your image

Don't worry about creating another image, just use `contentMode` property and set your image as you normally would (i.e. `[_img_view setImage:img];`)

Comment: If you are not sure do not post as an answer. And if you do don't be lazy about it :)

Comment: @giorashc you're right in saying I was lazy with my answer, however I believe I am giving the right answer, just not including the code to do it. SO should be about providing answers for questions, not necessarily providing code samples all the time

Comment: Saying look the content of view/aspect fit does not help much and should be posted as a comment imao. nevertheless now it looks as it should so +1 for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is what @EdgeAkpinar meant and should do the same as your method, only shorter.

```
UIImageView *imageView      = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]] autorelease];
imageView.contentMode       = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.frame             = CGRectMake(0, 0, 504, 320);
```

You dont need any changes on your image itself.

Comment: Where do you get the image from? If you for example use UIImagePickerController and take a new Photo, you can set the quality before saving. As far as I know quality always gets lower when you scale an image..